# convergence of $\bar{X}_n \to \bar{X}$ where $\bar{X} = X1_{(|X|\le M)}$

Tags: probability-theory

In Durrett's probability theory and examples, we have the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.6.8** Suppose $X_n \to X$ a.s. Let $g, h$ be continuous functions with 
> (i) $g \ge 0$ and $g(x)$ as $|x| \to \infty$,
> (ii) $|h(x)| /g(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$,
> (iii) $Eg(X_n) \le K < \infty$ for all $n$.
> Then $Eh(X_n) \to Eh(X).$
> Proof: By subtracting a constant from $h$, we can suppose without loss of generality that $h(0) = 0$. Pick $M$ large so that $P(|X| = M) = 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ when $|x| \ge M$. Given a random variable $X$, let $\bar{X} = X1_{(|X| \le M)}$. Since $P(|X| = M) = 0$, $\bar{X}_n \to \bar{X}$ a.s.

I don't understand the part "Since $P(|X| = M) = 0$, $\bar{X}_n \to \bar{X}$ a.s." Why do we need the $P(|X| = M) = 0$ condition to get $\bar{X}_n \to \bar{X}$ a.s.? From how I see it, since $X_n \to X$ a.s., the bounded versions of them should also converge almost surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_n=1+\frac 1n$ and $X=1$ the $X_n \to X$ a.s. but $\overline {X_n}$ does not converge to $\overline {X}$ when $M=1$ since $\overline {X_n}=0$ and $\overline {X} =1.$